# MySQL - How to handle case to use second foreign key if first foreign key is empty?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that produces heirarchical results from tables like:

- program

  - year

    - unit

      - rotation_discipline_block

        - week

          - learning_event

However, not all records in table `learning_event` for column `learning_event.week_fk` will have a relationship with a record in table `week`.  For example `week_fk` might be empty or `0`

In which case, I want to match the record in table `learning_event` on record in table `rotation_discipline_block` using the value in `learning_event.rotation_discipline_block_fk` to produce for those records a modified heirarchy:

- program

  - year

    - unit

      - rotation_discipline_block

        - learning_event

Table `learning_event`:

```
+-------------------+-----------------------+------------------------+----------+------------------------------+
| learning_event_pk |  learning_event_name  | learning_event_outcome | week_fk  | rotation_discipline_block_fk |
+-------------------+-----------------------+------------------------+----------+------------------------------+
```

Table `week`:

```
+---------+-----------+------------------------------+
| week_pk | week_name | rotation_dicsipline_block_fk |
+---------+-----------+------------------------------+
```

Table `rotation_discipline_block`:

```
+------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------+
| rotation_discipline_block_pk | rotation_discipline_block_name | unit_fk |
+------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------+
```

Table `unit`:

```
+---------+-----------+---------+
| unit_pk | unit_name | year_fk |
+---------+-----------+---------+
```

Table `year`:

```
+---------+-----------+------------+
| year_pk | year_name | program_fk |
+---------+-----------+------------+
```

Table `program`:

```
+------------+--------------+
| program_pk | program_name |
+------------+--------------+
```

How would I need to change the query below to do this?

```
SELECT CONCAT('program:', program_pk) AS global_id,
       program_name AS name,
       NULL AS parent_global_id,
       1 AS seq
FROM program
UNION ALL
SELECT CONCAT('year:', year_pk) AS global_id,
       year_name AS name,
       CONCAT('program:', program_fk) AS parent_global_id,
       2 AS seq
FROM year 
UNION ALL
SELECT 
       CONCAT('year:', year_fk, ',unit:', unit_name) AS global_id,
       unit_name AS name,
       CONCAT('year:', year_fk) AS parent_global_id,
       3 AS seq
FROM unit
UNION ALL
SELECT 
       CONCAT('year:', year_fk, ',unit:', unit_name, ',rotation_discipline_block:', rotation_discipline_block_name) AS global_id,
       rotation_discipline_block_name AS name,
       CONCAT('year:', year_fk, ',unit:', unit_name) AS parent_global_id,
       4 AS seq
FROM rotation_discipline_block rdb
INNER JOIN unit u ON u.unit_pk = rdb.unit_fk
UNION ALL
SELECT 
       CONCAT('year:', year_fk, ',unit:', unit_name, ',rotation_discipline_block:', rotation_discipline_block_name, ',week:', week_name) AS global_id,
       week_name AS name,
       CONCAT('year:', year_fk, ',unit:', unit_name, ',rotation_discipline_block:', rotation_discipline_block_name) AS parent_global_id,
       5 AS seq
FROM week wk
INNER JOIN rotation_discipline_block rdb ON rdb.rotation_discipline_block_pk = wk.rotation_discipline_block_fk
INNER JOIN unit u ON u.unit_pk = rdb.unit_fk
INNER JOIN year y ON u.year_fk = y.year_pk
UNION ALL
SELECT 
       CONCAT('year:', year_fk, ',unit:', unit_name, ',rotation_discipline_block:', rotation_discipline_block_name, ',week:', week_name, ',learning_event:', learning_event_name) AS global_id,
       learning_event_name AS name,
       CONCAT('year:', year_fk, ',unit:', unit_name, ',rotation_discipline_block:', rotation_discipline_block_name, ',week:', week_name) AS parent_global_id,
       6 AS seq
FROM learning_event le
INNER JOIN week wk ON wk.week_pk = le.week_fk
INNER JOIN rotation_discipline_block rdb ON rdb.rotation_discipline_block_pk = wk.rotation_discipline_block_fk
INNER JOIN unit u ON u.unit_pk = rdb.unit_fk
INNER JOIN year y ON u.year_fk = y.year_pk
ORDER BY seq ASC, 
    CASE seq
    WHEN 1 THEN 0 
    WHEN 2 THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(name, 6) AS SIGNED)
    WHEN 3 THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(name, -2) AS SIGNED)
    WHEN 4 THEN 0
    WHEN 5 THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(name, 6) AS SIGNED)
    WHEN 6 THEN 0
    END ASC,
    name  ASC
```

See  [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/phB9ZWPJQbVaCZVmbHv5QJ/1)

So, to recap:

- The parent of a record in table `learning_event` is **EITHER** a record
  in table `week` **OR** a record in table `rotation_discipline_block`.  Not both.
- The parent of a record in table `learning_event` is decided by the
  value of **EITHER** `learning_event.week_fk` **OR**
  `learning_event.rotation_discipline_block_fk`:

  - If `learning_event.week_fk` value > 0 then the parent is the
    corresponding value for `week_pk` in table `week`.
  - Else, if `learning_event.week_fk` value == 0 then the parent of the
    learning_event record is the matching record in table `rotation_discipline_block` as defined in `learning_event.rotation_discipline_block_fk`.  In which case, week is not in the heirarchy for the learning_event record.

This is illustrated by the two lists at the beginning of this question.

As examples:

In table `learning_event` there are two records:

```
(133, 'Antigen capture and processing', '', 0, 22),
(134, 'Antigen capture and presentation - MHC', '', 7, 0),
```

The first record above shows 0 for the week_fk column, and 22 for the `rotation_discipline_block_fk` column.  So the parent for this record should be the record in table `rotation_discipline_block` with `rotation_discipline_block_pk` of 22.

The second record above shows 7 for the `week_fk`, so the parent of this record should be the record in table `week` with the `week_pk` of 7.

See this in [Updated db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5fiF18h2xFeXyQ8cx5cb6K/0)

Comment: try case in join clause like `INNER JOIN week wk ON  case when  le.week_fk > 0  then wk.week_pk  = le.week_fk else wk.week_pk = le.rotation_discipline_block_fk end`

Comment: Thanks, but shouldn't be joining week at all if le.week_fk =  0...

Comment: *For example week_fk might be empty or 0* so i suggested this or you can use which suits your needs.

Comment: Instead it should be a case where INNER JOIN rotation_discipline_block rdb ON rdb.rotation_discipline_block_pk = le.rotation_discipline_block_fk if le.week_fk = 0

Comment: You can't use if inside there just use this skeleton `Join table1 t1 on case when <condition> then <table to join column> else <other column to be joined> end`

Comment: OK, thanks...A working answer based on my db-fiidle would be good...

Comment: Answer added, based on my theory.

Comment: Do the check inside application code.  FKs should not be depended no for anything non-trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `case` on Join,

```
SELECT CONCAT('program:', program_pk) AS global_id,
       program_name AS name,
       NULL AS parent_global_id,
       1 AS seq
FROM program
UNION ALL
SELECT CONCAT('year:', year_pk) AS global_id,
       year_name AS name,
       CONCAT('program:', program_fk) AS parent_global_id,
       2 AS seq
FROM year 
UNION ALL
SELECT 
       CONCAT('year:', year_fk, ',unit:', unit_name) AS global_id,
       unit_name AS name,
       CONCAT('year:', year_fk) AS parent_global_id,
       3 AS seq
FROM unit
UNION ALL
SELECT 
       CONCAT('year:', year_fk, ',unit:', unit_name, ',rotation_discipline_block:', rotation_discipline_block_name) AS global_id,
       rotation_discipline_block_name AS name,
       CONCAT('year:', year_fk, ',unit:', unit_name) AS parent_global_id,
       4 AS seq
FROM rotation_discipline_block rdb
INNER JOIN unit u ON u.unit_pk = rdb.unit_fk
UNION ALL
SELECT 
       CONCAT('year:', year_fk, ',unit:', unit_name, ',rotation_discipline_block:', rotation_discipline_block_name, ',week:', week_name) AS global_id,
       week_name AS name,
       CONCAT('year:', year_fk, ',unit:', unit_name, ',rotation_discipline_block:', rotation_discipline_block_name) AS parent_global_id,
       5 AS seq
FROM week wk
INNER JOIN rotation_discipline_block rdb ON rdb.rotation_discipline_block_pk = wk.rotation_discipline_block_fk
INNER JOIN unit u ON u.unit_pk = rdb.unit_fk
INNER JOIN year y ON u.year_fk = y.year_pk
UNION ALL
SELECT 
       CONCAT('year:', year_fk, ',unit:', unit_name, ',rotation_discipline_block:', rotation_discipline_block_name, ',week:', week_name, ',learning_event:', learning_event_name) AS global_id,
       learning_event_name AS name,
       CONCAT('year:', year_fk, ',unit:', unit_name, ',rotation_discipline_block:', rotation_discipline_block_name, ',week:', week_name) AS parent_global_id,
       6 AS seq
FROM year y
INNER JOIN unit u ON y.year_pk = u.year_fk
INNER JOIN rotation_discipline_block rdb ON u.unit_pk = rdb.unit_fk
INNER JOIN week wk ON rdb.rotation_discipline_block_pk = wk.rotation_discipline_block_fk
INNER JOIN learning_event le ON CASE WHEN le.week_fk = 0 THEN rdb.rotation_discipline_block_pk = le.rotation_discipline_block_fk ELSE wk.week_pk = le.week_fk END

ORDER BY seq ASC, 
    CASE seq
    WHEN 1 THEN 0 
    WHEN 2 THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(name, 6) AS SIGNED)
    WHEN 3 THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(name, -2) AS SIGNED)
    WHEN 4 THEN 0
    WHEN 5 THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(name, 6) AS SIGNED)
    WHEN 6 THEN 0
    END ASC,
    name  ASC
```

**Update:**

For `seq = 6` **Update:**

You can use two union queries, so the block will be as

```
#q1
SELECT 
CONCAT('year:', year_fk, ',unit:', unit_name, ',rotation_discipline_block:', rotation_discipline_block_name, ',week:', week_name, ',learning_event:', learning_event_name) AS global_id,
      lewk.learning_event_name AS name,
CONCAT('year:', year_fk, ',unit:', unit_name, ',rotation_discipline_block:', rotation_discipline_block_name, ',week:', week_name) AS parent_global_id,
       6 AS seq
FROM year y
INNER JOIN unit u ON y.year_pk = u.year_fk
INNER JOIN rotation_discipline_block rdb ON u.unit_pk = rdb.unit_fk
INNER JOIN week wk ON rdb.rotation_discipline_block_pk = wk.rotation_discipline_block_fk
INNER JOIN learning_event lewk ON wk.week_pk = lewk.week_fk and lewk.week_fk <> 0

UNION ALL

#q2
SELECT 
CONCAT('year:', year_fk, ',unit:', unit_name, ',rotation_discipline_block:', rotation_discipline_block_name, ',learning_event:', learning_event_name) AS global_id,
      lerdb.learning_event_name AS name,
CONCAT('year:', year_fk, ',unit:', unit_name, ',rotation_discipline_block:', rotation_discipline_block_name) AS parent_global_id,
       6 AS seq
FROM year y
INNER JOIN unit u ON y.year_pk = u.year_fk
INNER JOIN rotation_discipline_block rdb ON u.unit_pk = rdb.unit_fk
INNER JOIN learning_event lerdb ON rdb.rotation_discipline_block_pk = lerdb.rotation_discipline_block_fk AND lerdb.week_fk = 0;
```

So the working result will be as [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5fiF18h2xFeXyQ8cx5cb6K/4)

**Update:**

You can also remove the condition `lewk.week_fk <> 0` and `lerdb.week_fk = 0` from the `join` and can use in the where clause.

Comment: Again, Since you haven't said which column to be mapped directly i have added with the other one. You can now edit for your own.

Comment: There is a problem, as a learning_event (le) with week_fk = 0 and say, rotation_discipline_block_fk (rdb)  =  22, the le shows in all weeks matching the rdb - see le  (133, 'Antigen capture and processing', '', 0, 22), in https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5fiF18h2xFeXyQ8cx5cb6K/0  What needs to happen is the le appear as a child of the rdb and not in any weeks

Comment: *Would needs to happen is the le appear as a child of the rdb and not in any weeks* explain this part. Coz when I was writing I saw that everything matches with rdb 22 and so I couldn't see any other output since no related  columns were taken

Comment: 'What needs to happen is the le appear as a child of the rdb and not in any weeks' if the week_fk = 0 and there is a corresponding value in rotation_discipline_block_fk.  If this is the case, then the learning_event should show as a child of the rotation_discipline_block_name (rdb), not as child of any weeks that are related to the rdb (e.g. rdb with pk of 22 (Body defences)).  I think the only learning_events identified in that table to weeks are those belonging to the parent rdb with pk = 22, though that will ultimately change.

Comment: See the required heirachical structure in my OP where learning_event changes to have parent of rotation_discipline_block, instead of being child of week for the rotation_discipline_block

Comment: Yeah I get it, so now I have showed you the method how to use case using join. Now you can alter right?

Comment: The query is complex and I got a lot of help with this, but I think you would know better than I how to do this properly.  Can you update your answer with working fiddle and I will accept gladly.

Comment: Currently I have limited access. I can look into this but it will be tomorrow.

Comment: So clear me this,  when le.week_fk=0 then which table and it's column to join and what would be your expected output. If you edit your question and add your current output part( the last block) and desired output which you need.

Comment: How does the column result should be? For the sample which you have shared? `global_id, parent_global_id`

Comment: Just analyzed a bit more and shared my edit. Hope this would solve your problems.

Comment: Thanks but I'm getting an error in the db_fiddle...can you please provide a link to a working fiddle?

Comment: @IlludiumPu36 added.

Comment: Sorry James, you are very close. However your query requires that there is an entry in table week with a rotation_discipline_block_fk that matches learning_event.rotation_discipline_block_fk, otherwise the learning event doesn't show in the results.  An example in the fiddle in table learning_event is (135, 'Antigen recognition I - T cells', '', 0, 21)... this record doesn't show in the results because there is no week that matches in table week...we need to avoid table week altogether if learning_event.week_fk == 0 and there is a value in learning_event.rotation_disciplne_block_fk

Comment: Considering that I need this and how much work you have given to it, I will award a bounty of 50

Comment: Also, I don't think it needs GROUP BY global_id

Comment: Will add a detail explaination  btw I have changed the column what to be displayed. If you try executing without group by there will be duplicate entries in the result

Comment: OK, just make sure you update the fiddle with (135, 'Antigen recognition I - T cells', '', 0, 21)...this record should display in your fiddle with parent rotation_discipline_block.rotation_discipline_block_pk = 21 as a test case.  See  https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5fiF18h2xFeXyQ8cx5cb6K/2

Comment: But yesterday it was 133? now changed to 135.. alright will check. *An example in the fiddle in table learning_event is (135, 'Antigen recognition I - T cells', '', 0, 21)... this record doesn't show in the results because there is no week that matches in table week...we need to avoid table week altogether if learning_event.week_fk == 0 and there is a value in learning_event.rotation_disciplne_block_fk*.

Comment: First you said that when there is le.week=0 then it should join with rdb table but now it seems to be different, as i have already asked what kind of column result should be shown as a result for 135? `global_id, parent_global_id`

Comment: Nothing has changed.  Yes, le.week=0 then parent should be rdb table record.  Except in your fiddle from yesterday, for an LE to show in results where week=0 and rdb_fk = some number, there needed to be a record in the week table with that rdb_fk.  This should not be the case, that's all.

Comment: And yes, the example has changed, but it was just an example...

Comment: Okay, will share the updated one with your latest example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200376/discussion-between-illudiumpu36-and-james).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200392/discussion-on-answer-by-james-mysql-how-to-handle-case-to-use-second-foreign-k).